# Fancybox 3.0 title at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox 3.0 Beta 1 and I've got a problem with the title. I want the title at the top and not on the bottom.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside',
            position: 'top'
        }
    }
});
```

I've used this http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/ but it doesn't work, because its for fancybox 2.0 (which i thought it will work for 3.0 too but it wont).

Can you help me with moving the title to the top instead the bottom?

Thank you!

Comment: By title do you mean the lorem ipsum text you have in the title attribute? Because it's showing at the top for me in your fiddle

Comment: I can verify what @kevin is saying on Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Ubuntu 14.04 .

Comment: Hey, sorry guys for the unclear example. Yes, I mean the title that is at the top. But the working JSFiddle example is using Fancybox 2, I need this code for Fancybox 3 Beta 1.

Comment: Could you point where the Fancybox 3 can be found? I mean, it's better to provide the link in your question.

Comment: Yes, no problem. There is a little landingpage for Fancybox 3, but without any docs, thats the problem: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/beta/

Comment: Fancybox is now autonomous, you can't control it anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

The "title" in Fancybox 3 is called "caption". You can pass it to the HTML element as the `data-caption` attribute:

```
<a href="image.jpg" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

or as option to the JS Api:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : 'image.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'My caption',
            thumb   : 'thumbnail.jpg'
        }
    }
]);
```

It seems like the "title" option (e.g. text written above the content) is no longer supported. According to the developer, it would [look "outdated"](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/2091#issuecomment-427648701).

According to the docs, you should be able to "[completely change the look](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-4)" of your modal, by overriding the fancybox css rules. However, this doesn't seem really doable, since the `padding-bottom` used to create a space for the caption seems to be [set by the JS core](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/blob/4658124c989f8b5d831cefdead72fa8eea12e77d/src/js/core.js#L2320).

Comment: Title is on bottom, question is about title on top or inside

Comment: you're right, my fault. It doesn't seem possible at the moment. You might want to contact the author by filing an issue on github. https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues